# Mockito+ Rest-Assured not mocking in Spring Boot REST MVC application(Integration Testing)

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot, mockito

I was trying to write test cases for SpringBoot MVC rest application. I am able to run the test cases successfully. But when i tried to mock one of the methods, its not working. 
The test case still calls the original implementation.

Test class:-

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { Initializer.class,
        WebConfig.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SampleControllerTest {

    @Mock
    CounterUtil counterUtil;

    @InjectMocks
    PreProcessor preProcessor

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    private static boolean isSetup = false;
    @Test
    public void sampleTest() {              
        org.mockito.Mockito.when(
                counterUtil
                        .getCounter()).thenReturn(
                "2222");
        given().contentType("application/json").when()
        .get("/initialize").then()
        .statusCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();

            counterUtil = (CounterUtil) context
                    .getBean("counterUtil");    
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
             RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();

    }
}
```

The PreProcessor is a concreate class, with an instance of CounterUtil.

```
@Component
public class PreProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private CounterUtil counterUtil


    public void myMethod(){
        counterUtil.getCounter();
    }

}
```

These are the dependencies in pom.xml.

```
<!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Not getting any error. The execution works fine, but not considering the the mocked implementation.

Any suggestion or pointer is also welcomed.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the test runner @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Being a SpringMVC project for integration test I cant give any other test runner.

Comment: Maybe try MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

Comment: Thanks. MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)  is added to the @Before method.

Answer (score 2):

I Finally out it working!!!
Please find below the test class with the changed. Used  codes.org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils class for injesting the mock objects.

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { Initializer.class,
        WebConfig.class })
@WebIntegrationTest
public class SampleControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    CounterUtil counterUtil;

    @Autowired
    PreProcessor preProcessor

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    private static boolean isSetup = false;
    @Test
    public void sampleTest() {              
        org.mockito.Mockito.when(
                counterUtil
                        .getCounter()).thenReturn(
                "2222");
        given().contentType("application/json").when()
        .get("/initialize").then()
        .statusCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
            counterUtil = (CounterUtil) context
                    .getBean("counterUtil");   
            counterUtil = Mockito
                    .mock(CounterUtil.class);
            ReflectionTestUtils.setField(preProcessor,
                    "counterUtil", counterUtil);                    
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
             RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();

    }
}
```